# What is this, how to obtain information about a process ID

Tags: process, cpu, ps, top

How can I get more information than what `top` shows me about a process?

I currently have a process that displays as `j` and has the CPU running at +2400%. Searching for `j` yields no results.

Here's an example of the `top` output:

```
PID  USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM   TIME+     COMMAND                                                                             
1722 root  20   0 2118996  57076   1148 S  2488  0.2   43934:45  j
```

This is being run on `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)` using 2 x Intel Xeon E5-2660v3 with 2.60 GHz.

`ls -l /proc/1722/exe` gives me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 17:13 /proc/1722/exe -> /usr/games/j
```

`ls -lH /proc/1722/exe` gives me:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 313496 Dec 29 09:58 /proc/1722/exe
```

Comment: @kemotep I know the CPU display can be above 100% (e.g. mine is at +2500 right now). I need to identify what the process is doing, or what it is. How can I get more information about it?

Comment: have you tried using ps? `ps -p $PID` should tell you a little more. You will need to update your post to include more information such as what your Operating System is, if reporting that you have 24+ cores is wrong, etc.

Comment: @kemotep Yes, the `ps -p` showed almost the same info as `top`. `1722 ?        31-02:32:37 j` I've updated the question. The server has 20 cores.

Comment: What does `ls -l /proc/1722/exe` show? How about `ls -lH /proc/1722/exe`?

Comment: For a start, `/proc/1722/exe` will point to the `j` executable.  `/proc/1722/cwd` will point to the working directory of the process.  `/proc/1722/cmdline` will give the full command line (as NULL-separated tokens).

Comment: @chris85, when you get requests for more information, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/428137/edit) your question to include your response, rather than answering in comments.   Is that the full output from your `ls -l /proc/1722.exe`?  No symlink target `-> ...` ?

Comment: I read this question as being about what the process is, not the mechanics of using `top` or `ps`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [VirSCAN](http://r.virscan.org/report/d45e84d75a6088538ec36f010059aab2), this is a miner, which is consistent with the CPU usage you’re seeing. Its presence might indicate that your system has been compromised, the other option being that its users aren’t trustworthy; in any case you should probably stop the system, image the disk if you want to keep evidence or if you need any of the data stored there, and re-install.

See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) on Server Fault.